# Compare and combine multidimensional array then sort descending PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have 2 multi arrays, profiles and encoded arrays like this

```
    $profiles = array(
        array(
            'user_id'      => 'fcc3d884-fbef-438a-9c86-0ad52c9b1223',
            'first_name'   => 'Narñia',
            'middle_name'  => 'Ñ',
            'last_name'    => 'Cruz',
            'ext'          => ''
        ),
        array(
            'user_id'      => '0d31557d-1e9f-4db3-ac0d-72e1709fe89c',
            'first_name'   => 'Randy',
            'middle_name'  => 'O',
            'last_name'    => 'Rocker',
            'ext'          => ''
        ),
        array(
            'user_id'      => '0f93f169-cf56-49df-a76b-7596446104c6',
            'first_name'   => 'Qwerty',
            'middle_name'  => 'K',
            'last_name'    => 'Asdfg',
            'ext'          => ''
        ),
        array(
            'user_id'      => '23b1f4a2-034c-43b4-96b7-3191d78cead1',
            'first_name'   => 'Johny',
            'middle_name'  => 'L',
            'last_name'    => 'Walker',
            'ext'          => ''
        )
    );

    $encoded = array(
        array(
            'encoder_id' => '0d31557d-1e9f-4db3-ac0d-72e1709fe89c',
            'fullname'   => 'Randy O. Rocker',
            'encoded'    => 10,
        ),
        array(
            'encoder_id' => '23b1f4a2-034c-43b4-96b7-3191d78cead1',
            'fullname'   => 'John L. Walker',
            'encoded'    => 20,
        )
    );
```

Now i want to get some data from $profiles then combine to $encoded array when **user_id** and **encoder_id** is match, i have this code but it seems wrong it only gets "John L. Waler" data. here's my code.

```
    $data = [];
    foreach ($profiles as $key => $val) {
        $user_id = $val['user_id'];

        foreach($encoded as $k => $v){
            $ext_name = ($val['ext'] == '') ? '' : $val['ext'];
            $fullname = $val['first_name'].' '.substr($val['middle_name'], 0, 1).'. '.$val['last_name'].' '.$ext_name;
            $data[$key] = array(
                'id'       => ($v['encoder_id'] == $user_id) ? $v['encoder_id'] : $user_id,
                'fullname' => ($v['encoder_id'] == $user_id) ? $v['fullname'] : $fullname,
                'encoded'  => ($v['encoder_id'] == $user_id) ? $v['encoded'] : 0
            );
        }
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
    echo '</pre>';
```

here's the result

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => fcc3d884-fbef-438a-9c86-0ad52c9b1223
                [fullname] => Narñia �. Cruz 
                [encoded] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 0d31557d-1e9f-4db3-ac0d-72e1709fe89c
                [fullname] => Randy O. Rocker 
                [encoded] => 0 //this should be 10
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 0f93f169-cf56-49df-a76b-7596446104c6
                [fullname] => Qwerty K. Asdfg 
                [encoded] => 0
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 23b1f4a2-034c-43b4-96b7-3191d78cead1
                [fullname] => John L. Walker
                [encoded] => 20
            )

    )
```

Also after combining them to a new array. i want to **sort** the new array by "encoded" attribute **descending**.
Thank you for understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your life easier by re-indexing the `$encoded` array by the `encoder_id` values using [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php); then you don't have to search the array each time to look for a `user_id` value, you can just use [`isset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). Once you've extracted your data, you can use [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort by the `encoded` values:

```
$encoded_ids = array_column($encoded, null, 'encoder_id');

$data = array();
foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
    $user_id = $profile['user_id'];
    if (isset($encoded_ids[$user_id])) {
        $data[] = array('id' => $user_id,
                        'fullname' => $encoded_ids[$user_id]['fullname'],
                        'encoded' => $encoded_ids[$user_id]['encoded']
                        );
    }
    else {
        $data[] = array('id' => $user_id,
                        'fullname' => "${profile['first_name']} ${profile['middle_name']} ${profile['last_name']}",
                        'encoded' => 0
                        );
    }
}

usort($data, function ($a, $b) { return $b['encoded'] - $a['encoded'];});
print_r($data);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 23b1f4a2-034c-43b4-96b7-3191d78cead1
            [fullname] => John L. Walker
            [encoded] => 20
        )    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0d31557d-1e9f-4db3-ac0d-72e1709fe89c
            [fullname] => Randy O. Rocker
            [encoded] => 10
        )    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => fcc3d884-fbef-438a-9c86-0ad52c9b1223
            [fullname] => Narñia Ñ Cruz
            [encoded] => 0
        )    
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0f93f169-cf56-49df-a76b-7596446104c6
            [fullname] => Qwerty K Asdfg
            [encoded] => 0
        )    
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/FXtsE)

Comment: Is there any difference between that use of `array_combine` and just doing `array_column($encoded, null, 'encoder_id')` to reindex?

Comment: @Jeto none whatsoever! I'm *forever* forgetting that usage of `array_column`. Thanks for pointing it out, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Nick's version, using [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/array_reduce):

```
$encodedByEncoderId = array_column($encoded, null, 'encoder_id');

$combined = array_reduce($profiles, function (array $combined, array $profile) use ($encodedByEncoderId): array {
  $combined[] = [
    'id' => $profile['user_id'],
    'fullname' => $encodedByEncoderId[$profile['user_id']]['fullname'] 
      ?? "{$profile['first_name']} {$profile['middle_name']}. {$profile['last_name']}",
    'encoded' => $encodedByEncoderId[$profile['user_id']]['encoded'] 
      ?? 0
  ];
  return $combined;
}, []);
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/kKBru**

Comment: This isn't quite the same, when the `user_id` value exists in the `$encoded` array, OP takes the `fullname` from that array, not the `$profiles` array (`John L. Walker` instead of `Johny L. Walker`). You just need another null coalescing operator...

Comment: Oh, didn't realize the names were different. That's a bit weird. Fixed, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
$data = [];
foreach ($profiles as $key => $val) {
    $user_id = $val['user_id'];
    $is_matched = 0;
    $encoded_data = [];

    foreach($encoded as $k => $v){
        if ($user_id == $v['encoder_id']) {
            $is_matched = 1;
            $encoded_data = $v;
        }
    }
    $ext_name = ($val['ext'] == '') ? '' : $val['ext'];
    $fullname = $val['first_name'].' '.substr($val['middle_name'], 0, 1).'. '.$val['last_name'].' '.$ext_name;
    $data[$key] = array(
        'id'       => ($is_matched == 1) ? $encoded_data['encoder_id'] : $user_id,
        'fullname' => ($is_matched == 1) ? $encoded_data['fullname'] : $fullname,
        'encoded'  => ($is_matched == 1) ? $encoded_data['encoded'] : 0
    );
}
```

Comment: My pleasure! :)